# Laravel JsValidation is not working with Ajax submitted form

Tags: php, laravel, jsvalidation

I'm using `Laravel JsValidation`, `JsValidation` working properly with other forms, but because I should submit the form with Ajax, JsValidation is not working properly, and form submitted.

```
$validator = JsValidation::make($rules);
```

and in view

```
{!!$validator!!}
```

Comment: Is this the library that you're using https://github.com/proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation ?

Comment: `JsValidation is not working properly` is too vague, can you elaborate your problem.

Comment: @GauravDave Suppose I have a form that should be submitted with ajax, I have passed the validation rules to `JsValidator`, now because of submit of form with ajax, `JsValidator` can't prevent from submit of form, and the form is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Since the validation call is asynchronous, mark that as synchronous by doing:

```
async: false
```

[optional] and to prevent form submit default functionality, do:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

on submit button click. After doing validation you'll get response based on that response, you can allow form to submit or not.

> Simple Code Snippet:

```
$("#form-submit").on('submit', function(){
        var errorMsg = 'Please provide your correct information.';
        $(".errorMsg ").text("");
        var txtName = $("input#txtName").val();

        var responseStatus = false;
        var userData = {
            'name' : txtName
        };

        $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: '/validate-data',
           async: false,
           data: userData,
           success: function(result){
                if(result.status === true){
                    responseStatus = true;
                } else {
                    responseStatus = false;
                    errorMsg = result.message;
                    $(".errorMsg ").text(errorMsg);
                    return false;
               }
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                  alert('Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again.');                     return false;
             }
         });

     if(responseStatus === false){
          return false;
     } else {
          return true;
     }
});
```

See, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this snippet:

```
$('form').on('submit', function() {
  if($(this).valid()) {
    // do your ajax stuff here
  }
  return false;
});
```